# Using '(change)' event binding for nested angular component in Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-component-life-cycle

I am aware that '(change)' is a prebuilt event binder for input, select and textarea fields. But what does it mean when we use it as an event binder to a component?

Calling a component:

```
<dropdown-list [items]="countrycodes" (change) = "updateCCode($event)"  > </dropdown-list>
```

Inside dropdown-list component, there's a select box as well as a text box for filtering list. When a select box value is selected, I fire emit event which eventually fires 'updateCCode' event of the parent component.

Now if I edit the text field and remove focus, it surprisingly fires the 'updateCCode' event. Eventually, to get a workaround, I had to change the code to:

```
<dropdown-list [items]="countrycodes" (changeUpdated) = "updateCCode($event)"  > </dropdown-list>
```

so as to avoid firing of the default 'onChange' event since my event binder name was '(change)'.

**Question**

Is this a correct approach? Why does (change) event emitter when fired to a  component DOES NOT override the onChange native function? 
Should I implement some sort of onchange listener and have it call 'preventDefault' ?

Comment: I would remove the change event from the dropdown-list component and attach it to only the select box.

Comment: @RyanWilson but I need to send back some data to the parent component, hence need to use some event binder

Comment: What data do you need to send to the parent component?

Comment: Whatever the user selects in the child component after applying some sanitization and language translations.

Comment: You could potentially change the value of the parent component after applying sanitization and language translation during the change event of your child select-box, and if you still need to fire an event of the parent at that point, trigger its event.

Comment: drop-down component is used by many components like languages, countries, cities etc
But the context of my question is why the '(change)' event is fired implicitly even when I did not emit anything from child component

Comment: You changed the text of your search box which bubbles up to your dropdown-list.

Comment: I managed to do 'stopPropogation' on change event of text box which prevent bubbling up to the parent component

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it working.